# Sony vaio webcam not detected

Tags: windows-7, drivers, webcam, sony-vaio

I have a Sony vaio which will not detect its webcam. In device manager there is an unknown device under the USB section. I have tried updating the driver but it says it is up to date.

Visiting the Sony website is not helpful it simply says the webcam drivers aren't downloadable because windows provides them by default. However windows doesn't.

Is there anywhere I can safely download these generic drivers that should come with windows 7? Or are there actually some specific drivers? The Sony website is useless in providing thorough specs, the Sony retail shops are even worse at helping.

Comment: I downloaded them from the Sony website, The site is mostly helpful.

Comment: @Gigili can you please post a link to it? If you need an incentive I'll give you 100 reputation or something.

Comment: [Original Drivers and Applications for VPCS1 Series (Windows 7 64-Bit)](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/vpcs116fg). I don't need rep, thank you.

Comment: @Gigili, Thanks (I know, it's just that I desperately needed this answer and it's been too often when people have commented once and then not replied to follow up :))